# .pfx Certificates how to open don't have the pasword

Tags: certificate

I have a .pfx certificate, it is password protected.  I'm trying to open it.  I did not create it a co-worker who left the company has originally created it they do not have the passord any more.  Does anyone know how to open it.  It goes to an app that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

A PFX file includes the private key associated with the public key in the certificate. If a bad actor had the private key (s)he could masquerade as that server. Which is bad! Hence the need for a password on the PFX file. There's no way around it. If you don't have the password, you can't get into the file. I would try talking to the co-worker!

TL;DR: Nope, without the password, you can't open the PFX file.

Comment: Is there a way to remove or renane the .pfx file? Or is thier a way to create a new .pfx file and replace the old file?

Comment: if you have access to the old cert and private key, then sure, you should be able to create a new PFX file. but you need access to the cert and private key :)